# Redis installed on FreeBSD via pkg or ports can not run

Tags: redis, freebsd

I had installed redis on FreeBSD via pkg yesterday.And also add `redis_enable="YES"`in my `/etc/rc.conf`.

When I run `service redis start`,It displays `Starting redis`,but when run `service redis status`,displays `redis is not running`.

After run `redis-server`,It runs,but use `redis-cli` cannot connect the server.

When run `redis-cli` or `redis-cli ping`,it will jammed with no error.

The redis log file also has no error.

I cannot find the solution with google or others。How should I do to use redis?

The same with installed redis via `ports`

[image]
The followings are the base information about my company:

- FreeBSD version: 10.3-RELEASE-p18
- Pkg version: 1.10.1
- Redis version: 3.29

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to update, reinstall by doing this:

```
# pkg update
```

then:

```
# pkg upgrade -y
```

To reinstall redis:

```
# pkg remove -y redis
```

To install it again:

```
# pkg install -y redis
```

At this point you should see this in the terminal:

```
===>  CONFIGURATION NOTE:

  To setup "redis" you need to edit the configuration file:
  /usr/local/etc/redis.conf

  To run redis from startup, add redis_enable="YES"
  in your /etc/rc.conf.
```

To ensure [redis](https://redis.io/) is enabled on startup use [sysrc](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysrc)

```
# sysrc redis_enable="YES"
```

Not this time try to starting calling the script directly:

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/redis start
```

You could use `sockstat` to check if is up and listenin:

```
# sockstat -4l
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS
redis    redis-serv 9553  4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:6379        *:*
```

After this, redis-cli, or `telnet 0 6379` should be working:

```
# telnet 0 6379
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If that still not working, maybe [ktrace](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ktrace) can help to find more details:

To trace a PID:

```
$ ktrace -p 9553
```

To stop tracing:

```
# ktrace -C
```

use [kdump](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kdump) to display kernel trace data

```
# kdump -f my-ktrace.out | less
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do on BSD when a command "hungs" is to press ^T (ie ctrl-t).  Can you do that and paste the output?